# merge rows with the same timestamp into new column values

Tags: kql

I've got a bunch of log data from a KQL Table that I want to plot. Here's the simplified query:

```
MyDataTable
| where ['TimeGenerated'] >= ago(30m)
| summarize count=count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 15m), log_level
```

That gets me a table like this:

| "TimeGenerated [UTC]" | "log_level" | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "10/19/2022, 11:00:00.000 PM" | info | 3527 |
| "10/19/2022, 11:00:00.000 PM" | warn | 33 |
| "10/19/2022, 11:00:00.000 PM" | error | 2 |
| "10/19/2022, 11:15:00.000 PM" | info | 5274 |
| "10/19/2022, 11:15:00.000 PM" | warn | 42 |
| "10/19/2022, 11:15:00.000 PM" | error | 5 |
| "10/19/2022, 11:30:00.000 PM" | info | 1553 |
| "10/19/2022, 11:30:00.000 PM" | warn | 15 |
| "10/19/2022, 11:30:00.000 PM" | error | 1 |

But I want to combine the entries with the same timestamp and put the count into different columns based on log_level. Essentially, I want to end up with this:

| "TimeGenerated [UTC]" | info | warn | error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "10/19/2022, 11:00:00.000 PM" | 3527 | 33 | 2 |
| "10/19/2022, 11:15:00.000 PM" | 5274 | 42 | 5 |
| "10/19/2022, 11:30:00.000 PM" | 1533 | 15 | 1 |

Any tips on how to do that transformation?

PS: An ideal solution would create new columns dynamically depending on the different values of `log_level` but if I have to use `info`/`warn`/`error` in the query that's better than the current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want a [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin)

```
datatable(TimeGenerated:datetime, LogLevel:string, Count:long)
[
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:00:00.000 PM), "info", 3527,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:00:00.000 PM), "warn", 33,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:00:00.000 PM), "error", 2,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:15:00.000 PM), "info", 5274,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:15:00.000 PM), "warn", 42,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:15:00.000 PM), "error", 5,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:30:00.000 PM), "info", 1553,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:30:00.000 PM), "warn", 15,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:30:00.000 PM), "error", 1,
]
| evaluate pivot(LogLevel, sum(Count))
```

Answer (score 2):

the solution below uses:

- [`bag_pack()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packfunction)
- [`make_bag()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-bag-aggfunction)
- [`bag_unpack()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-unpackplugin)

```
datatable(TimeGenerated:datetime, LogLevel:string, Count:long)
[
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:00:00.000 PM), "info", 3527,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:00:00.000 PM), "warn", 33,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:00:00.000 PM), "error", 2,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:15:00.000 PM), "info", 5274,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:15:00.000 PM), "warn", 42,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:15:00.000 PM), "error", 5,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:30:00.000 PM), "info", 1553,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:30:00.000 PM), "warn", 15,
    datetime(10/19/2022 11:30:00.000 PM), "error", 1,
]
| extend p = pack(LogLevel, Count)
| summarize b = make_bag(p) by TimeGenerated
| evaluate bag_unpack(b)
```

| TimeGenerated | error | info | warn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-19 23:00:00.0000000 | 2 | 3527 | 33 |
| 2022-10-19 23:15:00.0000000 | 5 | 5274 | 42 |
| 2022-10-19 23:30:00.0000000 | 1 | 1553 | 15 |

Comment: Thanks for this example. I think the bag-based code could be useful for some of my other queries, but for this specific problem a pivot table is more straightforward.